# tomcat remote debug mode in linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, tomcat

I am setting tomcat in debug mode. Tomcat server is running on different machine and I am working on different machine.

Before starting tomcat I am executing following linux command.

```
iptables -I INPUT  -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 9003 -j ACCEPT
export JPDA_ADDRESS=9003
export JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
export JPDA_SUSPEND=n
bin/catalina.sh jpda start
```

In eclipse I am providing IP address of remote machine and port number 9003.

My ./catalina.sh file is given below. But still I am not able to see green color debug pointers at breakpoint. What to do ? Eclipse doesn't throw any exception while connecting to remote machine. Earlier it was throwing 'Connection failed' but once I executed following command it was rectified, but not able to see breakpoints even after I have given breakpoints.

```
iptables -I INPUT  -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 9003 -j ACCEPT
```

my `cataline.sh` file.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Control Script for the CATALINA Server
#
# Environment Variable Prerequisites
#
#   Do not set the variables in this script. Instead put them into a script
#   setenv.sh in CATALINA_BASE/bin to keep your customizations separate.
#
#   CATALINA_HOME   May point at your Catalina "build" directory.
#
#   CATALINA_BASE   (Optional) Base directory for resolving dynamic portions
#                   of a Catalina installation.  If not present, resolves to
#                   the same directory that CATALINA_HOME points to.
#
#   CATALINA_OUT    (Optional) Full path to a file where stdout and stderr
#                   will be redirected.
#                   Default is $CATALINA_BASE/logs/catalina.out
#
#   CATALINA_OPTS   (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "start",
#                   "run" or "debug" command is executed.
#                   Include here and not in JAVA_OPTS all options, that should
#                   only be used by Tomcat itself, not by the stop process,
#                   the version command etc.
#                   Examples are heap size, GC logging, JMX ports etc.
#
#   CATALINA_TMPDIR (Optional) Directory path location of temporary directory
#                   the JVM should use (java.io.tmpdir).  Defaults to
#                   $CATALINA_BASE/temp.
#
#   JAVA_HOME       Must point at your Java Development Kit installation.
#                   Required to run the with the "debug" argument.
#
#   JRE_HOME        Must point at your Java Runtime installation.
#                   Defaults to JAVA_HOME if empty. If JRE_HOME and JAVA_HOME
#                   are both set, JRE_HOME is used.
#
#   JAVA_OPTS       (Optional) Java runtime options used when any command
#                   is executed.
#                   Include here and not in CATALINA_OPTS all options, that
#                   should be used by Tomcat and also by the stop process,
#                   the version command etc.
#                   Most options should go into CATALINA_OPTS.
#
#   JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS (Optional) Lists of of colon separated directories
#                   containing some jars in order to allow replacement of APIs
#                   created outside of the JCP (i.e. DOM and SAX from W3C).
#                   It can also be used to update the XML parser implementation.
#                   Defaults to $CATALINA_HOME/endorsed.
#
#   JPDA_TRANSPORT  (Optional) JPDA transport used when the "jpda start"
#                   command is executed. The default is "dt_socket".
#
#   JPDA_ADDRESS    (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "jpda start"
#                   command is executed. The default is 8000.
#
#   JPDA_SUSPEND    (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "jpda start"
#                   command is executed. Specifies whether JVM should suspend
#                   execution immediately after startup. Default is "n".
#
#   JPDA_OPTS       (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "jpda start"
#                   command is executed. If used, JPDA_TRANSPORT, JPDA_ADDRESS,
#                   and JPDA_SUSPEND are ignored. Thus, all required jpda
#                   options MUST be specified. The default is:
#
#                   -agentlib:jdwp=transport=$JPDA_TRANSPORT,
#                       address=$JPDA_ADDRESS,server=y,suspend=$JPDA_SUSPEND
#
#   CATALINA_PID    (Optional) Path of the file which should contains the pid
#                   of the catalina startup java process, when start (fork) is
#                   used
#
#   LOGGING_CONFIG  (Optional) Override Tomcat's logging config file
#                   Example (all one line)
#                   LOGGING_CONFIG="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties"
#
#   LOGGING_MANAGER (Optional) Override Tomcat's logging manager
#                   Example (all one line)
#                   LOGGING_MANAGER="-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# OS specific support.  $var _must_ be set to either true or false.
cygwin=false
darwin=false
os400=false
case "`uname`" in
CYGWIN*) cygwin=true;;
Darwin*) darwin=true;;
OS400*) os400=true;;
esac

# resolve links - $0 may be a softlink
PRG="$0"

while [ -h "$PRG" ]; do
  ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`
  link=`expr "$ls" : '.*-> \(.*\)$'`
  if expr "$link" : '/.*' > /dev/null; then
    PRG="$link"
  else
    PRG=`dirname "$PRG"`/"$link"
  fi
done

# Get standard environment variables
PRGDIR=`dirname "$PRG"`

# Only set CATALINA_HOME if not already set
[ -z "$CATALINA_HOME" ] && CATALINA_HOME=`cd "$PRGDIR/.." >/dev/null; pwd`

# Copy CATALINA_BASE from CATALINA_HOME if not already set
[ -z "$CATALINA_BASE" ] && CATALINA_BASE="$CATALINA_HOME"

# Ensure that any user defined CLASSPATH variables are not used on startup,
# but allow them to be specified in setenv.sh, in rare case when it is needed.
CLASSPATH=

if [ -r "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh" ]; then
  . "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh"
elif [ -r "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh" ]; then
  . "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh"
fi

# For Cygwin, ensure paths are in UNIX format before anything is touched
if $cygwin; then
  [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] && JAVA_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$JAVA_HOME"`
  [ -n "$JRE_HOME" ] && JRE_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$JRE_HOME"`
  [ -n "$CATALINA_HOME" ] && CATALINA_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$CATALINA_HOME"`
  [ -n "$CATALINA_BASE" ] && CATALINA_BASE=`cygpath --unix "$CATALINA_BASE"`
  [ -n "$CLASSPATH" ] && CLASSPATH=`cygpath --path --unix "$CLASSPATH"`
fi

# For OS400
if $os400; then
  # Set job priority to standard for interactive (interactive - 6) by using
  # the interactive priority - 6, the helper threads that respond to requests
  # will be running at the same priority as interactive jobs.
  COMMAND='chgjob job('$JOBNAME') runpty(6)'
  system $COMMAND

  # Enable multi threading
  export QIBM_MULTI_THREADED=Y
fi

# Get standard Java environment variables
if $os400; then
  # -r will Only work on the os400 if the files are:
  # 1. owned by the user
  # 2. owned by the PRIMARY group of the user
  # this will not work if the user belongs in secondary groups
  . "$CATALINA_HOME"/bin/setclasspath.sh
else
  if [ -r "$CATALINA_HOME"/bin/setclasspath.sh ]; then
    . "$CATALINA_HOME"/bin/setclasspath.sh
  else
    echo "Cannot find $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setclasspath.sh"
    echo "This file is needed to run this program"
    exit 1
  fi
fi

# Add on extra jar files to CLASSPATH
if [ ! -z "$CLASSPATH" ] ; then
  CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH":
fi
CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH""$CATALINA_HOME"/bin/bootstrap.jar

if [ -z "$CATALINA_OUT" ] ; then
  CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out
fi

if [ -z "$CATALINA_TMPDIR" ] ; then
  # Define the java.io.tmpdir to use for Catalina
  CATALINA_TMPDIR="$CATALINA_BASE"/temp
fi

# Add tomcat-juli.jar to classpath
# tomcat-juli.jar can be over-ridden per instance
if [ -r "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/tomcat-juli.jar" ] ; then
  CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$CATALINA_BASE/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
else
  CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$CATALINA_HOME/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
fi

# Bugzilla 37848: When no TTY is available, don't output to console
have_tty=0
if [ "`tty`" != "not a tty" ]; then
    have_tty=1
fi

# For Cygwin, switch paths to Windows format before running java
if $cygwin; then
  JAVA_HOME=`cygpath --absolute --windows "$JAVA_HOME"`
  JRE_HOME=`cygpath --absolute --windows "$JRE_HOME"`
  CATALINA_HOME=`cygpath --absolute --windows "$CATALINA_HOME"`
  CATALINA_BASE=`cygpath --absolute --windows "$CATALINA_BASE"`
  CATALINA_TMPDIR=`cygpath --absolute --windows "$CATALINA_TMPDIR"`
  CLASSPATH=`cygpath --path --windows "$CLASSPATH"`
  JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS=`cygpath --path --windows "$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS"`
fi

# Set juli LogManager config file if it is present and an override has not been issued
if [ -z "$LOGGING_CONFIG" ]; then
  if [ -r "$CATALINA_BASE"/conf/logging.properties ]; then
    LOGGING_CONFIG="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties"
  else
    # Bugzilla 45585
    LOGGING_CONFIG="-Dnop"
  fi
fi

if [ -z "$LOGGING_MANAGER" ]; then
  LOGGING_MANAGER="-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"
fi

# Uncomment the following line to make the umask available when using the
# org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener
#JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=`umask`"

# ----- Execute The Requested Command -----------------------------------------

# Bugzilla 37848: only output this if we have a TTY
if [ $have_tty -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "Using CATALINA_BASE:   $CATALINA_BASE"
  echo "Using CATALINA_HOME:   $CATALINA_HOME"
  echo "Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: $CATALINA_TMPDIR"
  if [ "$1" = "debug" ] ; then
    echo "Using JAVA_HOME:       $JAVA_HOME"
  else
    echo "Using JRE_HOME:        $JRE_HOME"
  fi
  echo "Using CLASSPATH:       $CLASSPATH"
  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
    echo "Using CATALINA_PID:    $CATALINA_PID"
  fi
fi

if [ "$1" = "jpda" ] ; then
  if [ -z "$JPDA_TRANSPORT" ]; then
    JPDA_TRANSPORT="dt_socket"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_ADDRESS" ]; then
    JPDA_ADDRESS="8000"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_SUSPEND" ]; then
    JPDA_SUSPEND="n"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_OPTS" ]; then
    JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=$JPDA_TRANSPORT,address=$JPDA_ADDRESS,server=y,suspend=$JPDA_SUSPEND"
  fi
  CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS $JPDA_OPTS"
  shift
fi

if [ "$1" = "debug" ] ; then
  if $os400; then
    echo "Debug command not available on OS400"
    exit 1
  else
    shift
    if [ "$1" = "-security" ] ; then
      if [ $have_tty -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "Using Security Manager"
      fi
      shift
      exec "$_RUNJDB" "$LOGGING_CONFIG" $LOGGING_MANAGER $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
        -Djava.endorsed.dirs="$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" \
        -sourcepath "$CATALINA_HOME"/../../java \
        -Djava.security.manager \
        -Djava.security.policy=="$CATALINA_BASE"/conf/catalina.policy \
        -Dcatalina.base="$CATALINA_BASE" \
        -Dcatalina.home="$CATALINA_HOME" \
        -Djava.io.tmpdir="$CATALINA_TMPDIR" \
        org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start
    else
      exec "$_RUNJDB" "$LOGGING_CONFIG" $LOGGING_MANAGER $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
        -Djava.endorsed.dirs="$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" \
        -sourcepath "$CATALINA_HOME"/../../java \
        -Dcatalina.base="$CATALINA_BASE" \
        -Dcatalina.home="$CATALINA_HOME" \
        -Djava.io.tmpdir="$CATALINA_TMPDIR" \
        org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start
    fi
  fi

elif [ "$1" = "run" ]; then

  shift
  if [ "$1" = "-security" ] ; then
    if [ $have_tty -eq 1 ]; then
      echo "Using Security Manager"
    fi
    shift
    eval exec "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" "\"$LOGGING_CONFIG\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
      -Djava.endorsed.dirs="\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\"" -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" \
      -Djava.security.manager \
      -Djava.security.policy=="\"$CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.policy\"" \
      -Dcatalina.base="\"$CATALINA_BASE\"" \
      -Dcatalina.home="\"$CATALINA_HOME\"" \
      -Djava.io.tmpdir="\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\"" \
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start
  else
    eval exec "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" "\"$LOGGING_CONFIG\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
      -Djava.endorsed.dirs="\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\"" -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" \
      -Dcatalina.base="\"$CATALINA_BASE\"" \
      -Dcatalina.home="\"$CATALINA_HOME\"" \
      -Djava.io.tmpdir="\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\"" \
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start
  fi

elif [ "$1" = "start" ] ; then

  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
    if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
      if [ -s "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
        echo "Existing PID file found during start."
        if [ -r "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
          PID=`cat "$CATALINA_PID"`
          ps -p $PID >/dev/null 2>&1
          if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
            echo "Tomcat appears to still be running with PID $PID. Start aborted."
            exit 1
          else
            echo "Removing/clearing stale PID file."
            rm -f "$CATALINA_PID" >/dev/null 2>&1
            if [ $? != 0 ]; then
              if [ -w "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
                cat /dev/null > "$CATALINA_PID"
              else
                echo "Unable to remove or clear stale PID file. Start aborted."
                exit 1
              fi
            fi
          fi
        else
          echo "Unable to read PID file. Start aborted."
          exit 1
        fi
      else
        rm -f "$CATALINA_PID" >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? != 0 ]; then
          if [ ! -w "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
            echo "Unable to remove or write to empty PID file. Start aborted."
            exit 1
          fi
        fi
      fi
    fi
  fi

  shift
  touch "$CATALINA_OUT"
  if [ "$1" = "-security" ] ; then
    if [ $have_tty -eq 1 ]; then
      echo "Using Security Manager"
    fi
    shift
    eval "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" "\"$LOGGING_CONFIG\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
      -Djava.endorsed.dirs="\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\"" -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" \
      -Djava.security.manager \
      -Djava.security.policy=="\"$CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.policy\"" \
      -Dcatalina.base="\"$CATALINA_BASE\"" \
      -Dcatalina.home="\"$CATALINA_HOME\"" \
      -Djava.io.tmpdir="\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\"" \
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start \
      >> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 "&"

  else
    eval "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" "\"$LOGGING_CONFIG\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
      -Djava.endorsed.dirs="\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\"" -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" \
      -Dcatalina.base="\"$CATALINA_BASE\"" \
      -Dcatalina.home="\"$CATALINA_HOME\"" \
      -Djava.io.tmpdir="\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\"" \
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start \
      >> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 "&"

  fi

  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
    echo $! > "$CATALINA_PID"
  fi

  echo "Tomcat started."

elif [ "$1" = "stop" ] ; then

  shift

  SLEEP=5
  if [ ! -z "$1" ]; then
    echo $1 | grep "[^0-9]" >/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
      SLEEP=$1
      shift
    fi
  fi

  FORCE=0
  if [ "$1" = "-force" ]; then
    shift
    FORCE=1
  fi

  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
    if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
      if [ -s "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
        kill -0 `cat "$CATALINA_PID"` >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
          echo "PID file found but no matching process was found. Stop aborted."
          exit 1
        fi
      else
        echo "PID file is empty and has been ignored."
      fi
    else
      echo "\$CATALINA_PID was set but the specified file does not exist. Is Tomcat running? Stop aborted."
      exit 1
    fi
  fi

  eval "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER $JAVA_OPTS \
    -Djava.endorsed.dirs="\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\"" -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" \
    -Dcatalina.base="\"$CATALINA_BASE\"" \
    -Dcatalina.home="\"$CATALINA_HOME\"" \
    -Djava.io.tmpdir="\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\"" \
    org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" stop

  # stop failed. Shutdown port disabled? Try a normal kill.
  if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
      echo "The stop command failed. Attempting to signal the process to stop through OS signal."
      kill -15 `cat "$CATALINA_PID"` >/dev/null 2>&1
    fi
  fi

  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
    if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
      while [ $SLEEP -ge 0 ]; do
        kill -0 `cat "$CATALINA_PID"` >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
          rm -f "$CATALINA_PID" >/dev/null 2>&1
          if [ $? != 0 ]; then
            if [ -w "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
              cat /dev/null > "$CATALINA_PID"
              # If Tomcat has stopped don't try and force a stop with an empty PID file
              FORCE=0
            else
              echo "The PID file could not be removed or cleared."
            fi
          fi
          echo "Tomcat stopped."
          break
        fi
        if [ $SLEEP -gt 0 ]; then
          sleep 1
        fi
        if [ $SLEEP -eq 0 ]; then
          if [ $FORCE -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Tomcat did not stop in time. PID file was not removed. To aid diagnostics a thread dump has been written to standard out."
            kill -3 `cat "$CATALINA_PID"`
          fi
        fi
        SLEEP=`expr $SLEEP - 1 `
      done
    fi
  fi

  KILL_SLEEP_INTERVAL=5
  if [ $FORCE -eq 1 ]; then
    if [ -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
      echo "Kill failed: \$CATALINA_PID not set"
    else
      if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
        PID=`cat "$CATALINA_PID"`
        echo "Killing Tomcat with the PID: $PID"
        kill -9 $PID
        while [ $KILL_SLEEP_INTERVAL -ge 0 ]; do
            kill -0 `cat "$CATALINA_PID"` >/dev/null 2>&1
            if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
                rm -f "$CATALINA_PID" >/dev/null 2>&1
                if [ $? != 0 ]; then
                    if [ -w "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
                        cat /dev/null > "$CATALINA_PID"
                    else
                        echo "The PID file could not be removed."
                    fi
                fi
                # Set this to zero else a warning will be issued about the process still running
                KILL_SLEEP_INTERVAL=0
                echo "The Tomcat process has been killed."
                break
            fi
            if [ $KILL_SLEEP_INTERVAL -gt 0 ]; then
                sleep 1
            fi
            KILL_SLEEP_INTERVAL=`expr $KILL_SLEEP_INTERVAL - 1 `
        done
        if [ $KILL_SLEEP_INTERVAL -gt 0 ]; then
            echo "Tomcat has not been killed completely yet. The process might be waiting on some system call or might be UNINTERRUPTIBLE."
        fi
      fi
    fi
  fi

elif [ "$1" = "configtest" ] ; then

    eval "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER $JAVA_OPTS \
      -Djava.endorsed.dirs="\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\"" -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" \
      -Dcatalina.base="\"$CATALINA_BASE\"" \
      -Dcatalina.home="\"$CATALINA_HOME\"" \
      -Djava.io.tmpdir="\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\"" \
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap configtest
    result=$?
    if [ $result -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Configuration error detected!"
    fi
    exit $result

elif [ "$1" = "version" ] ; then

    "$_RUNJAVA"   \
      -classpath "$CATALINA_HOME/lib/catalina.jar" \
      org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo

else

  echo "Usage: catalina.sh ( commands ... )"
  echo "commands:"
  if $os400; then
    echo "  debug             Start Catalina in a debugger (not available on OS400)"
    echo "  debug -security   Debug Catalina with a security manager (not available on OS400)"
  else
    echo "  debug             Start Catalina in a debugger"
    echo "  debug -security   Debug Catalina with a security manager"
  fi
  echo "  jpda start        Start Catalina under JPDA debugger"
  echo "  run               Start Catalina in the current window"
  echo "  run -security     Start in the current window with security manager"
  echo "  start             Start Catalina in a separate window"
  echo "  start -security   Start in a separate window with security manager"
  echo "  stop              Stop Catalina, waiting up to 5 seconds for the process to end"
  echo "  stop n            Stop Catalina, waiting up to n seconds for the process to end"
  echo "  stop -force       Stop Catalina, wait up to 5 seconds and then use kill -KILL if still running"
  echo "  stop n -force     Stop Catalina, wait up to n seconds and then use kill -KILL if still running"
  echo "  configtest        Run a basic syntax check on server.xml - check exit code for result"
  echo "  version           What version of tomcat are you running?"
  echo "Note: Waiting for the process to end and use of the -force option require that \$CATALINA_PID is defined"
  exit 1

fi
```

Comment: export JPDA_SUSPEND=n should be y rather than n?  That should cause the process to suspend?  I think.

Comment: @Gavin I tried both. no output

Comment: Its been years since i did this on eclipse, but I always found it to be flaky, always seemed you had to get the timing just right or some such.  Silly question, have you tried  having the debug session running then starting tomcat?

Comment: @Gavin yes tried that too